# Compile Simple OpenSSL C code With MinGW

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile simple C code which calls OpenSSL MD5 function to generate Encrypted string with MinGW64, but I am getting error **"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"**

My C Code that calls MD5 function is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char string[] = "happy";

    MD5((unsigned char*)&string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)&digest);

    char mdString[33];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    printf("md5 digest: %s\n", mdString);

    return 0; 
}
```

The command I am using to compile this code is **"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc program.c -I /usr/include/ -lcrypto -lssl -o output.exe
"**

Is there any way to get actual error or what I am missing??

Comment: Is there a longer error message that the part you posted? I would guess that one of the libraries is either unavailable, or not where the compiler expected; but without a full error message it's hard to be sure.

Comment: there isn't any long error @KevinBoone. I am just getting error "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status".

Comment: Is there any way to log commands executed by bash?

Comment: You can run `bash -x {script or commands}`. Where are `libcrypto.dll` and `libssl.dll`?